# Lambda Expression doesn't work for filtering obj in a list

Tags: c#, winforms, lambda

User select month, and dynamically 4 textbox + a button (save row) for each day will be drawn; every textbox has the textbox.Tag = day who refers.

When user click on save row I will it to select only the textboxes of the corresponding row (expecting 4 textboxes).

code that generate the textboxes:

```cs
foreach (DateTime day in monthDays)
{
    var t1 = new TextBox();
    t1.Location = new Point(Origin.X + 90, Origin.Y + 30 * Ycounter);
    t1.Size = new Size(40, 25);
    t1.MaxLength = 5;
    t1.Tag = day;
    AutoControls.Add(t1);
    Controls.Add(t1);
```

I try this:

```cs
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = (Button)sender;
    DateTime d = (DateTime)b.Tag;

    List<TextBox> t = new List<TextBox>(AutoControls.OfType < TextBox());

    //Autocontrols it's the list with ALL the dynamically generates controls in that form.


    var g = t.Where(x => x.Tag == b.Tag); // expecting 4 textboxes, but returns 0
    var g = t.Where(x => x.Tag == b.Tag).ToList(); // 0
    var g = t.FindAll(x => x.Tag == b.Tag); //returns  0
```

Any help is very appreciated ^_^

Comment: What are the values of `monthDays` and `d`?

Comment: monthDays it's a DateTime list ( from 1st to last day of given month), d it's for example the 1st day of the month {01/06/2019 00:00:00}

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing two `object` directly, and by default this will be done by references comparison.

```
// this for example will never be true, even if today is 20190613
// because they are 2 different instances
(object)new DateTime(2019, 06, 13) == (object)DateTime.Today
```

You want to compare the value of these date instead:

```
t.Where(x => x.Tag is DateTime date && date == d)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Control> RecordData = Controls.Cast<Control>().Where(x => x.Tag is DateTime date && date == d).ToList();
```

I've create this code starting from the suggestions of Xiaoy312 (Thanks ^^) and reading about Cast command on similar threads.